# Trouble with adding key-value pairs a nested dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I've been banging my head against the wall about this problem, and I feel like I'm really close! But not quite there yet.
Any help is hugely appreciated. The format of the question will take some explaining but I don't think the coding itself will be very hard for you guys.
I'm trying to write a function that takes the information inside a CSV file and creates a nested dictionary.
Lines in the CSV file looks like this:

```
....  
2001,Spring,AFR 202 - 01,18,30,T|F,01:30 pm - 02:40 pm  
2002,Fall,AFR 208 - 01,29,30,M|Th,09:50 am - 11:00 am   
....
```

There are several hundred or so lines in the CSV. It's not necessary for you to pay close attention to any
of the values in the CSV other than the year and the season (first two in each line), since I've taken care 
of stuff involving that.

The function should print out a nested dictionary with the calendar years as the keys on the top level. 
Each of these keys has a value as a dictionary, which in turn has as keys the two semesters Fall and Spring. 
To each season, I'm associating a list of dictionaries, one for every line in the dictionary.

So, it should look something like this (formatted for readability):

```
{
  "2001": {
    "Fall": [
      {
        "one": 40,
        "two": "AFR 207 - 01",
        "three": "W",
        "four": 44,
        "five": "Fall",
        "six": "07:00 pm - 09:30 pm",
        "seven": "2001"
      },
      ...
    ],
    "Spring": [
      {
        ...
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  "2002" : {
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Explained another way, each year is a key in the biggest dictionary, and each key-value pair looks a bit like this:

```
year : { fall:[{ ...information...}],spring[{...information}] }
```

For each line in the CSV file, I have the {...information...} part down, and for each year I can pull out lines from the CSV and attach it to the appropriate year. I'm having trouble, though, getting both the 'fall' and the 'spring' lists to appear inside of the 'year' dictionary.

Note: entries in allClassInfo were made by formatting lines from the CSV file, and they look like this:

```
....
{'four': 15, 'one': 15, 'three': 'M|Th', 'six': '01:30 pm - 02:40 pm', 'two': 'WRIT 135 - 01', 'five': 'Fall', 'seven': '2014'},
{'four': 15, 'one': 15, 'three': 'M|Th', 'six': '02:50 pm - 04:00 pm', 'two': 'WRIT 140 - 01', 'five': 'Fall', 'seven': '2014'}
....
```

My code:

```
def byYear(filename):
    allClassInfo = classInfo(filename)
    bigDict={}
    for entry in allClassInfo:

        if ((entry.get('seven') in bigDict)  == False):
            if (entry.get('five') == 'Spring'):
                bigDict[entry.get('year')]= {'Spring':[entry]}

        if ((entry.get('seven') in bigDict)  == False):
            if (entry.get('five') == 'Fall'):
                bigDict[entry.get('year')]['Fall'] = [{'Fall':[entry]}]

    print bigDict

byYear('name.csv')
```

Which outputs things like:

```
'2008': {'Spring': [{'four': 50, 'one': 5, 'three': 'T|F', 'six': '09:50 am - 11:00 am', 'two': 'AFR 105 - 01', 'five': 'Spring', 'seven': '2008'}]}, 
'2009': {'Spring': [{'four': 25, 'one': 11, 'three': 'M|W|Th', 'six': '08:30 am - 09:40 am', 'two': 'AFR 102 - 01', 'five': 'Spring', 'seven': '2009'}]}
```

But no Fall info.

And I haven't gotten this far yet, but once each year is made, I'd include all of the other information by including some code like this:

```
    if ((entry.get('year') in bigDict)  == True):
        if (entry.get('semester') == 'Fall'):
            bigDict[entry.get('year')]['Fall'].append('entry')
        if (entry.get('semester') == 'Spring'):
            bigDict[entry.get('year')]['Spring'].append(entry)
```

Comment: will you include a link of the file(a small part of it) from which you're reading this data. It'll be more helpful to answer your question then

Comment: Here is the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19iowRqorpaKg6qphyf1mhqSoNOb2YEacdaUd9xs7AIk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
if (entry.get('five') == 'Spring'):
    bigDict[entry.get('year')]= {'Spring':[entry]}
```

this line will over write the contents in `bigDict[entry.get('year')]`. 
To add key-value pair to `dict`, you can:

```
if (entry.get('five') == 'Spring'):
    bigDict[entry.get('year')]['Spring'] = [entry]
```

Comment: Thank you! I see now how it's overwriting. When I put in the code you suggested, however, after some printing my text editor gives me 'KeyError: '2001'' Do you know why this might happen? Is the 'Spring' key being created when as well as being added to when we write bigDict[entry.get('year')]['Spring'] ?

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries have a `setdefault` function which will make this much easier. If the given key is already present in the dict, it will return the value for the key, otherwise it will create the key/value pair.

```
bigDict = {}
for entry in allClassInfo:
    year = entry.get('seven')
    season = entry.get('five')

    # first, make sure we have an entry for this year in bigDict
    yearDict = bigDict.setdefault(year, {})
    # then make an entry for this season
    list = yearDict.setdefault(season, [])
    # then, append to the list
    list.append(entry)
```

NOTE: This works because the inserted dict is returned by reference. For simple value types use `get`. Eg. this is how you'd count entries:

```
counts = {}
for entry in allClassInfo:
    year = entry.get('seven')
    counts[year] = counts.get(year, 0) + 1
```

Comment: Wow cool! Thanks so much. I'm a little confused about how to use this to put in all of the other {...information...}s, though, since when I use this I /do/ get the complete framework with the years and seasons and all, but only the information from one line is in each Spring and Fall dictionary.

Comment: Ah I missed that in your question. To add a list to `yearDict`, you can use the same function again.